# String object has no attribute read

Tags: python, string, file

I'm getting an error when attempting to read a JSON file:

```
def get_mocked_json(self, filename):
    f = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), '../fixtures', filename)
    if os.path.exists(f) is True:
        return json.loads(f.read())
    else:
        return 'mocked.json'
```

This is the error:

```
           if os.path.exists(f) is True:
---->          return json.loads(f.read())
           else:
               return 'mocked.json'

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Any help in what I am doing wrong would be much appreciated.

Comment: `' '.join()` results in a string type. so you're performing `.read()` on a string

Comment: `f` - is your string with path, you can not call `read()` method on string

Answer (score 2):

Your `f` is just a string and strings can't be read. I think the source of the confusion here is that the `os.path` functions just ensure that the *string* represents a valid file-*path* on your operating system.

To actually `read` it, you need to `open` the file first. That will return a stream that can be `read`:

```
def get_mocked_json(self, filename):
    f = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), '../fixtures', filename)
    if os.path.exists(f) is True:
        with open(f) as fin:  # this is new
            return json.loads(fin.read())
    else:
        ...
```

Note that `if os.path.exists(...)` could be subject to race conditions. What would happen if between the `if` and the `open` the file was removed by another process? Or if you don't have permission to open it?

This can be avoided by `try`ing to open it and handling the case where it wasn't possible:

```
def get_mocked_json(self, filename):
    f = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), '../fixtures', filename)
    try:
        with open(f) as fin:
            return json.loads(fin.read())
    except Exception:  # or IOError
        ...
```

Comment: Thank you @MSeifert much, appreciated